# Why would you add the modules array in app/etc/config.php to source control?

Tags: module, magento2.2, magento2.3, array, deployment

As of Magento 2.2 it's recommended [to add `config.php` to your source control to facilitate pipeline deployment](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/config-php.html). I have some questions and issues with this. I'm hoping somebody can share their experience and give me some insights into this recommendation.

A very simplified way to describe the deployment process would be that the Magento build steps are executed in this order:

1. `bin/magento setup:di:compile`
2. `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. `bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated`

By adding certain configuration to `config.php` step #1 and #2 can be executed without a connection to a database and thus on a separate server without turning on maintenance mode. You'll always need a connection to the database for step #3.

In `config.php` there are 3 arrays that you'll need before you can run step #1 and #2: `modules`, `system` and `scopes`.

I have an issue with adding `config.php` to my source control because of the `modules` array. I'll explain why.

In the `modules` array Magento adds the modules in a specific order determined by the `<sequence/>` tags in the `module.xml` files. [It's not recommended to change this manually](https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-dont-manually-edit/). The state of the module (enabled or disabled) is also stored in `modules`.

I've run some tests and for the `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy` it doesn't seem to matter if a module is added to the `modules` array. Magento will still compile and deploy the files for that module.

When running `setup:upgrade` Magento will regenerate the `modules` array and will override the previous order if necessary.

So it seems that `modules` is necessary for `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy` but the actual content of the `modules` array doesn't really matter.

When working with feature branches and release branches in your GIT repository `config.php` is a file that becomes prone to merge conflicts. And because it's not recommended to manually change this file, you need to let Magento regenerate it which is kind of a hassle when merging pull requests.

How do you manage `config.php`? 
Does anyone know a good reason why is `modules` necessary before running `setup:upgrade`?

Answer (score 3):

It is necessary because it ensures all developers run the app with same disabled/enabled modules and config.

I run into conflicts with config.php a lot due to changed module array. I haven't put this into practice but I'm thinking of removing all unused modules from codebase with composer map directive and always have magento auto generate the module array from all modules installed, instead of committing config.php.

Of course if you use pipeline deployment and dump config then it does not work for you.